# How to use Applicative for concurrency?

Tags: scala, concurrency, functional-programming, applicative, haxl

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687378/concurrent-data-access-as-in-haxl-and-stitch). I copied the example below from [Haxl](https://github.com/facebook/Haxl)

Suppose I am fetching data from a blog server to render a blog page, which contains the recent posts, popular posts and posts topics.

I have the following Data Fetching API:

```
val getRecent  : Server => Seq[Post] = ...
val getPopular : Server => Seq[Post] = ...
val getTopics  : Server => Seq[Topic] = ...
```

Now I need to compose them to implement a new function `getPageData`

```
val getPageData: Server => (Seq[Post],  Seq[Post], Seq[Topic])
```

[Haxl](https://github.com/facebook/Haxl) suggests using a new monad `Fetch` to make the API composable.

```
val getRecent  : Fetch[Seq[Posts]] = ...
val getPopular : Fetch[Seq[Posts]] = ...
val getTopics  : Fetch[Seq[Topic]] = ...
```

Now I can define my `getPageData: Fetch[A]` with *monadic* composition

```
val getPageData = for {
  recent  <- getRecent
  popular <- getPopular
  topics  <- getTopics
} yield (recent, popular, topics)
```

but it does not run `getRecent`, `getPopular`, and `getTopics` concurrently.

[Haxl](https://github.com/facebook/Haxl) suggests using *applicative* composition `<*>` to compose "concurrent" functions (i.e. the functions that can run concurrently). So my questions are:

- How to implement `getPageData` assuming `Fetch[A]` is an `Applicative` ?
- How to implement `Fetch` as an `Applicative` but not a `Monad` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to implement getPageData assuming Fetch[A] is an Applicative ?

All we need to do is drop the monadic bind `>>=` in favour of the applicative `<*>`. So instead of

```
val getPageData = for {
  recent  <- getRecent
  popular <- getPopular
  topics  <- getTopics
} yield (recent, popular, topics)
```

we would write something like (in Haskell syntax; sorry, I can't do Scala off the top of my head):

```
getPageData = makeTriple <$> getRecent <*> getPopular <*> getTopics
  where
    makeTriple x y z = (x, y, z)
```

But whether this has the desired effect is contingent upon the second question!

> How to implement Fetch as an Applicative but not a Monad ?

The key distinction between monadic and applicative sequencing is that the monadic one can depend upon the value inside a monadic value, whereas the applicative `<*>` cannot. Notice how the monadic expression for `getPageData` above binds the names `recent` and `popular` before reaching `getTopics`. Those names *could have* been used to change the structure of the expression, for example by getting some other data source in case `recent` is empty. But with the applicative expression, the results of `getRecent` and `getPopular` are not factors in the structure of the expression itself. This property allows us to fire off each term in the applicative expression concurrently, because we know the structure of the expression statically.

So, using the observation above, and obviously the particular shape of the Fetch datatype, we can come up with a suitable definition for `<*>`. I think the following illustrates the general idea:

```
data Fetch a = Fetch { runFetch :: IO a }

fetchF <*> fetchX = Fetch $ do
  -- Fire off both IOs concurrently.
  resultF <- async $ runFetch fetchF
  resultX <- async $ runFetch fetchX
  -- Wait for both results to be ready.
  f <- wait resultF
  x <- wait resultX
  return $ f x
```

For comparison, suppose we tried to do monadic bind with concurrent evaluation:

```
fetchF >>= fetchK = Fetch $ do
  resultF <- async $ runFetch fetchF
  -- Oh no, we need resultF in order to produce the next
  -- Fetch value! We just have to wait...
  f <- wait resultF
  fetchX <- async $ runFetch (fetchK f)
  x <- wait $ runFetch fetchX
  return $ f x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not know `Haskell` that's why I am asking ... Do you define `Fetch[A]` as a record with a field `runFetch` of type `IO[A]` ?

Comment: That's right, Fetch[A] has a record runFetch which is IO[A]. So Fetch[A] is really just a new name for IO[A], allowing us to give the new `>>=` and `<*>` definitions.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I got it. BTW `Haxl` defines `Fetch` differently, I will try to read again and probably ask more questions here.

Comment: No problem! Yes my definition of `Fetch` is just for illustration of the general idea behind getting concurrency out of an applicative where it wouldn't be possible in a monad. I believe Haxl's fetch is necessarily more complicated because it handles caching.

Comment: Haxl's `Fetch` is just a tree; `<*>` just adding a new node. They  have also a  separate `fetch` function, which _interpretes_ the `Fetch` tree and actually fetches the data. The `fetch` handles all those caching, batching, async. etc.