# How to define Applicative in this case?

Tags: scala, concurrency, monads, applicative

This is a follow-up to my previous [quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591599/are-futures-in-scala-really-functional). I am reading this [post](http://futurice.com/blog/an-example-of-functional-design) again to understand the design described there.

They introduce a `Job` monad similar to [Haxl](https://code.facebook.com/posts/302060973291128/open-sourcing-haxl-a-library-for-haskell/). `Job[T]` is a data fetch operation that fetches data of type `T` (and may consist of other operations, i.e. it is a data fetches sequence).

```
sealed trait Job[+T]
case class PureJob[T](value: T) extends Job[T] 
case class BlockedJob[S,T](f: S => Job[T], job: Job[S]) extends Job[T]
case class FetchJob[T](url: Url) extends Job[T]

def pure[T](value: T): Job[T] = PureJob(value)

def flatMap[S,T](f: S => Job[T], job: Job[S]): Job[T] = 
  job match {
    case PureJob(value) => f(value)
    case _ => BlockedJob(f, job)
  }
```

They introduce also a function `execute` to *actually* execute a `Job[T]` operation and return a future.

```
def execute[T](job: Job[T])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = { ... }
```

For *concurrent* data fetching they add new `PairJob`, and `MapJob`:

```
case class MapJob[S, T](f: S => T, job: Job[S]) extends Job[T]
case class PairJob[S, T](jobS: Job[S], jobT: Job[T]) extends Job[(S, T)]
```

Now they can write:

```
val jobA: FetchJob[A] = ...
val jobB: FetchJob[B] = ...
val f: A => B = ...

// jobAB is a MapJob of "f" and PairJob of jobA and jobB
val jobAB = (jobA |@| jobB) {(a, b) => f(a, b)}
```

My question is how to define `Job[T]` as `Applicative` to write code as in the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well has soon has you have PairJob, you have what you need for applicative.

With any generic type G, (here, that would be Job)

if you have pairing:

```
def pair[A,B](ga: G[A], gb: G[B]): G[(A,B)]
```

(which for Job, is just `PairJob(ga, gb)`)

and also map, then you can easily implement apply

```
def ap[A, B](ga: ⇒ G[A])(f: ⇒ G[A ⇒ B]): G[B] = {
   val argAndFunc : G[(A, A => B)] = pair(ga, f)
   argAndFunc map {case (arg, func) => func(arg)}
}
```

The reverse is true, if you have ap and map, you easily get pair

```
def pair[A,B](ga: G[A], gb: G[B]): G[(A,B)] = {
  val pairWithB : G[B => (A,B]) = ga map {a => b: B => (a,b)}
  ap(gb)(pairWithB)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can always define map in terms of flatMap and pure:

```
def map[A,B](fa: Job[A])(f: A=>B): Job[B] = fa flatMap (f andThen pure)
```

and then you can define ap in terms of map and flatMap:

```
def ap[A,B](fa: => Job[A])(f: => Job[A => B]): Job[B] = 
  fa flatMap { a =>
    f map (_(a))
  }
```

or with for comprehension sugar:

```
def ap[A,B](fa: => Job[A])(f: => Job[A => B]): Job[B] = 
  for {
    a <- fa
    ff <- f
  } yield ff(a)
```

or you can skip map:

```
def ap[A,B](fa: => Job[A])(f: => Job[A => B]): Job[B] =
  fa flatMap { a =>
    f flatMap { ff => pure(ff(a)) }
  }
```