# Scala Future/Promise fast-fail pipeline

Tags: multithreading, scala, promise

I want to launch two or more Future/Promises in parallel and fail even if one of the launched Future/Promise fails and dont want to wait for the rest to complete.
What is the most idiomatic way to compose this pipeline in Scala.

EDIT: more contextual information.

I have to launch two external processes one writing to a fifo file and another reading from it. Say if the writer process fails; the reader thread might hang forever waiting for any input from the file. So I would want to launch both the processes in parallel and **fail fast** even if one of the Future/Promise fails without waiting for the completion of the other.

Below is the sample code to be more precise. the commands are not exactly `cat` and `tail`. I have used them for brevity.

```
val future1 = Future { executeShellCommand("cat file.txt > fifo.pipe") }
val future2 = Future { executeShellCommand("tail fifo.pipe") }
```

Comment: please, provide usage examples, otherwise your question is too broad (and might be even duplicate). `firstCompletedOf`, or just `flatMap/for-comprehension` or something more complex might fit your needs - but we need real examples to give an appropriate and exhaustive answer

Comment: @dk14 I have provided more info. Let me know if any more clarification is required.

Comment: it seems like actors (like akka) or streams (like fs2-io) fit better if you reading chunk-by-chunk or line-by-line and don't mind external libraries. Some code sample could be still useful. For instance, `Future` won't save you from hanging (if you use blocking-io inside - processing thread will still hang), and `Promise` should be treated very carefully

Comment: @dk14.. I have added sample code to avoid any more ambiguity. My application runs on Akka.. but for technical reasons I cannot use Akka here..

Comment: please be aware that none of the proposed solutions (including `Future.isCompletedOf`) is gonna cancel the thread that reads the output of `tail fifo.pipe` - The system will have zombie thread, which is gonna prevent all attached memory including any buffers from cleaning by GC and also lock fifo.pipe "forever" (at least in Windows/Cygwin you probably won't have the ability to delete it). You should manually close the pipe after some timeout.

Comment: there was an old Scala issue about this problem. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8994

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, what we are looking for is a fail-fast sequence implementation, which is akin to a failure-biased version of `firstCompletedOf`

Here, we eagerly register a failure callback in case one of the futures fails early on, ensuring that we fail as soon as any of the futures fail.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
def failFast[T](futures: Seq[Future[T]]): Future[Seq[T]] = {
  val promise = Promise[Seq[T]]
  futures.foreach{f => f.onFailure{case ex => promise.failure(ex)}}
  val res = Future.sequence(futures)
  promise.completeWith(res).future
}
```

In contrast to `Future.sequence`, this implementation will fail as soon as *any* of the futures fail, regardless of ordering.
Let's show that with an example:

```
import scala.util.Try
// help method to measure time
def resilientTime[T](t: =>T):(Try[T], Long) = {
  val t0 = System.currentTimeMillis
  val res = Try(t)
  (res, System.currentTimeMillis-t0)
}

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await
```

First future will fail (failure in 2 seconds)

```
val f1 = Future[Int]{Thread.sleep(2000); throw new Exception("boom")}
val f2 = Future[Int]{Thread.sleep(5000); 42}
val f3 = Future[Int]{Thread.sleep(10000); 101}
val res = failFast(Seq(f1,f2,f3))

resilientTime(Await.result(res, 10.seconds))
// res: (scala.util.Try[Seq[Int]], Long) = (Failure(java.lang.Exception: boom),1998)
```

Last future will fail. Failure also in 2 seconds. (note the order in the sequence construction)

```
val f1 = Future[Int]{Thread.sleep(2000); throw new Exception("boom")}
val f2 = Future[Int]{Thread.sleep(5000); 42}
val f3 = Future[Int]{Thread.sleep(10000); 101}
val res = failFast(Seq(f3,f2,f1))

resilientTime(Await.result(res, 10.seconds))
// res: (scala.util.Try[Seq[Int]], Long) = (Failure(java.lang.Exception: boom),1998)
```

Comparing with `Future.sequence` where failure depends on the ordering (failure in 10 seconds):

```
val f1 = Future[Int]{Thread.sleep(2000); throw new Exception("boom")}
val f2 = Future[Int]{Thread.sleep(5000); 42}
val f3 = Future[Int]{Thread.sleep(10000); 101}
val seq = Seq(f3,f2,f1)

resilientTime(Await.result(Future.sequence(seq), 10.seconds))
//res: (scala.util.Try[Seq[Int]], Long) = (Failure(java.lang.Exception: boom),10000)
```

Comment: your implementation (in general) has a risk of `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Promise already completed` (being surprisingly printed in logs) as you might call `promise.failure` twice if two or more futures are failed.

Comment: also, you could express the same with `import Future._; firstCompletedOf(seq).flatMap(_ => sequence(seq))` but the question isn't for result explicitly

Comment: and all of this doesn't cancel the fact that `tail` might hang forever and scala-library (in contrast to Java) doesn't provide any way to cancel it. Neither `firstCompleteOf` nor your solution doesn't cancel the actual thread in JVM.

Comment: @dk14 thanks , you mean the onFailure part of future must be wrapped in a try and ignore java.lang.IllegalStateException exceptions?. tail hanging part will be handled by me .. since I have ways to kill the processes on cleanup..

Comment: @dk14 I have added a guard expression to the pattern match to handle more than one future failing.

Comment: @maasg is there any way to kill all other futures once we catch exception in one?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Future.sequence`:

```
val both = Future.sequence(Seq(
  firstFuture,
  secondFuture));
```

This is the correct way to aggregate two or more futures where the failure of one fails the aggregated future and the aggregated future completes when all inner futures complete. An older version of this answer suggested a for-comprehension which while very common would not reject immediately of one of the futures rejects but rather wait for it.

Comment: the question seems too broad to actually know, how many futures is going to be composed. Talking abou your example i would add something like `val first Future = ...`, `val secondFuture = ...` to make clear that futures are obtained prior `for-comprehension`-composition, as one might copy-paste this and accidentally run futures in a sequential way. That's actually an issue with for comprehension - it actually fits better (but not limited by, of-course) to sequential composition

Comment: @dk14 this indeed is based on the fact futures are proxies for values (and not actions) and by the point you obtained a future the action is already in-flight. I understood the question in a pretty clear cut way - wait for two futures and fail if one fails. I only spotted the ambiguity after I read the comment discussion.

Comment: In second thought, I think  `Future.sequence` would probably be better since in this answer `firstFuture` must finish before `secondFuture` is checked for failure. I'll update to that.

Comment: "this indeed is based on the fact futures are proxies for values (and not actions)" agree, but it's only true for scala-library (as its futures are actually mutable and their composition might not be referentially transparent due to non-deterministic issues). scalaz/fs2/monix Future/Task is actually about action itself (so do-notation is almost always sequential there).

Comment: Anyway, question's update suggests that something might hang out, so it's hard to find an exhaustive answer without knowing which underlying API was used for IO-operations

Comment: I agree, I changed the answer to use `Future.sequence` since a for comprehension would hang if the first future hangs but the second rejects and this doesn't. In general it's not really possible to solve the case _they both hang_ but if it is guaranteed only one might fail at a time then this will suffice. I'm interested in what you meant by scala futures being mutable (vs monix futures) - in general I've rarely seen singular singular "future"s used as actions (outside cases where the _language_ is "lazy" like Haskell's IO) used this way and I'm very interested in reading more about it.

Comment: 1) the problem with hanging future is that it actually might hang the thread it's being executed on if there is no appropriate timeout (very depends on what kind of IO and how it is used), so first, even future inside `Future.sequence` will hang the resulting one, that's why `Future.firstCompletedOf` is more eppropriate 2) thread might might be blocked forever (even `firstCompleteOf` doesn't control it) holding JVM resources

Comment: 2) scalaz/fs2/monix `Task` is very often being used as Haskell's `IO` monad. It might even be used without a thread-pool (operations like `map` don't require it). I'll try to dig something up, but the key difference is that in scala-library, when you call `map` - you actually add a listener on futures result (which is side-effect) and it returns a `Future` representing this result (basically it calls Promis.complete inside that listener). In scalaz/etc - calling `map` (or something else) doesn't fire any actions at all - it just creates a new Task that is reffering to the previous one.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591599/are-futures-in-scala-really-functional/27591803) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/3zofjl/why_is_future_totally_unusable/) with quick googling

Comment: I think Future.sequence doesn't fail fast.. if waits for all the constituent to complete with a value or an exception..

Comment: @mig-foxbat Yes, it is the same as `zip`. `Future.firstCompletedOf`fails fast

Answer (score 0):

**Zip the futures**

```
val f1 = Future { doSomething() }
val f2 = Future { doSomething() }

val resultF = f1 zip f2
```

`resultF` future fails if any one of `f1` or `f2` is failed

*Time taken to resolve is `min(f1time, f2time)`*

```
scala> import scala.util._
import scala.util._

scala> import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent._

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val f = Future { Thread.sleep(10000); throw new Exception("f") }
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@da1f03e

scala> val g = Future { Thread.sleep(20000); throw new Exception("g") }
g: scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@634a98e3

scala> val x = f zip g
x: scala.concurrent.Future[(Nothing, Nothing)] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3447e854

scala> x onComplete { case Success(x) => println(x) case Failure(th) => println(th)}

result: java.lang.Exception: f
```

Comment: this doesn't fail fast either. say I do Await.result(f1 zip f2, Duration.Inf) and
if f2 fails in 10'th second and f1 succeeds in say 50'th second.. the Await doesn't end in 10'th second but at 50'th.

Comment: @mig-foxbat it works. editing the answer. please check

Comment: @mig-foxbat here is the example f  fails after 10 sec and g fails after 20 sec .... result is f exception not g exception

Comment: yeah the results are not a problem.. but the result should resolve in 10 seconds here instead of 20 seconds.. as soon as f fails I want the result to resolve and not wait for for g to resolve.

Comment: @mig-foxbat .. observe carefully the result in the base case has resolved in 10 secs not 20 secs

Comment: @mig-foxbat .. thats the reason why I cross checked it in the repl. it works ..it will not wait until all the futures fail it will immediately return once one of them fails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123128/discussion-between-mig-foxbat-and-pamu).