# list of futures - kill all of them when exception occur

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, queue, future

I am submitting 1000s of jobs asynchronously using scala futures. I have also implemented a ThrottledExecutionContext backed by a concurrent blocking queue so it keep running only 100 jobs max at a time and put the rest in queue.  It's a blocking operation as it involved calling 3rd party service within itself. When one of them throws an exception I need to either retry entire operation (1000s of jobs) or skip that entire batch. I can not retry when some of the futures are still running. I have a way to know that at any given point how many jobs are running in third party system (`spark`).  So once i catch an exception I want to first kill all the rest of the futures, empty the queue, wait for third party to finish any pending jobs for that batch and then retry. So is there a way to kill all futures upon exception in one?

I tried failFast based on following discussion but it's not doing what I expected. I don't have better understanding of `Promise` yet. but it seems we can control future of `Future` with `Promise`!

[Scala Future/Promise fast-fail pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437457/scala-future-promise-fast-fail-pipeline)

```
  var atomicnt = new AtomicInteger() // to track how many jobs were finished when exception occured

  def failFast[T](futures: Seq[Future[T]]): Future[Seq[T]] = {
    val promise = Promise[Seq[T]]
    futures.foreach{f => f.onFailure{case ex => promise.failure(ex)}}
    val res = Future.sequence(futures)
    promise.completeWith(res).future
  }

  def normalTask() =  {
    println("Starting normaltask")
    Thread.sleep(2000 + Random.nextInt(5000))
    if(Random.nextDouble() > 0.5) {
      println("Throwing random exception..")
      throw new RuntimeException("Random exception from normalTask")
    }
    atomicnt.getAndIncrement
    Thread.sleep(2000 + Random.nextInt(5000))
    println("Finished normaltask")
  }

  def testException() = {
    val rg = (0 until 500)
    val futures = rg.map(i =>{
      Future(normalTask)
    })
    val res = failFast(futures)
    Await.result(res, Duration.Inf) //blocking here to wait for all 500 to finish    
  }

  def batchProcessing() {
    
    try {
      println("Starting batchProcessing")
      testException()
      println("Exiting batchProcessing")      
    } catch {
      case t: Throwable => {
        println("Error in main")
        Thread.sleep(10000) //Here while waiting other futures are still running
        t.printStackTrace()
        // retry logic goes here based on failure or entire batch will be skipped 
      }
    }
    
  }
```

However when i catch exception in `batchProcessing` other futures are still running.

Other option I tried for parallel processing was to use Parallel collection which seemed to work. ie. entire parallel operation fails if any of the task fail. However, problem with that is throughput which is bounded by no of cpus I have available. Since all tasks are long running and blocking parallel collection doesn't feel right approach there.

Comment: The following is recommended reading on the topic: https://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-protips-6.html

Answer (score 3):

In built scala `Future` can't be interrupted once started.

Seems like you need something like monix Task or ZIO which can be interrupted and retried very easily.